# How can I webscrape data from json-ld piece of code?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, json-ld

I´m trying to get the coordinates ('latitude' and 'longitude') from these json-ld piece of code.

```
> <script type="application/ld+json">
> {"@context":"http://schema.org","@graph":[
>   {"@type":"Place","address":
>       {"@type":"PostalAddress","streetAddress":"XX, XX"},"geo":
>       {"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":50.08872,"longitude":20.0297}}]}
> </script>
```

The closest I was:

```
req = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
text_ = json.loads("".join(soup.find("script", {"type":"application/ld+json"}).contents)
```

But even this script is giving me a previous json-ld block of code (the first one in full html code).

I´d appreciate even getting the json-ld block like a string.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<script type="application/ld+json">
{"@context":"http://schema.org","@graph":[
  {"@type":"Place","address":
      {"@type":"PostalAddress","streetAddress":"XX, XX"},"geo":
      {"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":50.08872,"longitude":20.0297}}]}
</script>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
goal = soup.select_one("script").string
match = json.loads(goal)
print(type(match))
print(match)
```

```
<class 'dict'>
{'@context': 'http://schema.org', '@graph': [{'@type': 'Place', 'address': {'@type': 'PostalAddress', 'streetAddress': 'XX, XX'}, 'geo': {'@type': 'GeoCoordinates', 'latitude': 50.08872, 'longitude': 20.0297}}]}
```